# issue cloning a specific Git repository

Tags: git

I've been having issues with pullng from a specific Git repository on AFS.
When I use 'git pull' in the command line I get:

```
remote: Counting objects: 39, done.
```

and then it freezes. It never downloads anything.

I have tried this from other machines with the same result. i have also tried using SourceTree on a windows machine with no success. 
The issue only happens in this repository, but my colleagues do not have the same problems.
I really have no idea why this would happen. your thoughts appricated.

Comment: Which version of git are you using? Execute `git version`.

Comment: Which operating system is this by the way?

Answer (score 0):

With the provided context, it's difficult to pin point the root cause, but I would try:

- running `git fetch --verbose`. So if problem is in downloading the repo files, more details are shown.
- Change the transport protocol (SSH/HTTP), If the remote repo supports different protocols.
- Try a fetch with `-n`to avoid fetching tags (so a smaller download size)